# Formula for the number of integer solutions of an equation (using generating functions)

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $a_n$ be the number of integer solutions of $$i+3j+3k=n$$ where $i \geq 0, j \geq 2, k \geq 3$.

I want to use the generating function of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ to get a formula for $a_n$.

We just introduced generating functions, so I'm fairly new to this stuff and hope you can help me solve this problem.

I began by interpreting the problem as a power series. Without the restrictions for $i, j, k$ I get
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\dots)^2.$$
Accounting for $i \geq 0, j \geq 2, k \geq 3$ should get me something like
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)(x^6+x^9+x^{12}+\dots)(x^9++x^{12}+x^{15}+\dots).$$
Is that correct?

Now I tried to simplify this like this:
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
$$x^6+x^9+x^{12}+\dots
=(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+x^{12}+\dots)-(1+x^3)
=\frac{1}{1-x^3}-(1+x^3)
=\frac{x^6}{1-x^3}$$
and likewise
$$x^9++x^{12}+x^{15}+\dots = \frac{x^9}{1-x^3}.$$
So I have
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)(x^6+x^9+x^{12}+\dots)(x^9++x^{12}+x^{15}+\dots)
=\frac{x^{15}}{(1-x)(1-x^3)^2}.$$

I hope I didn't make a mistake already. In any case, here I'm stuck. I have to find a formula for the $n$-th coefficient in this power series, but I don't know how to do it.

---

[edit]

I'm still quite confused, but I'll try to go over it again one by one. Here is again the complete (and hopefully correct) partial fraction decomposition and my try to expand it:
$$\frac{1}{(1 - x)^3 (x^2 + x + 1)^2} \\
=\frac{1}{27} \frac{7x + 8}{x^2 + x + 1}
+ \frac{1}{9} \frac{2x+1}{(x^2 + x + 1)^2}
+ \frac{1}{27} \frac{7}{1-x}
- \frac{1}{9} \frac{2}{(1-x)^2}
+ \frac{1}{9} \frac{1}{(1-x)^3} \\
=\frac{1}{27} \frac{(7x + 8)(1-x)}{(1-x^3)}
+ \frac{1}{9} \frac{(2x+1)(1-x)^2}{(1-x^3)^2}
+ \frac{1}{27} \frac{7}{1-x}
- \frac{1}{9} \frac{2}{(1-x)^2}
+ \frac{1}{9} \frac{-1}{(1-x)^3} \\
=\frac{ (7x + 8)(1-x)}{27} \sum x^{3n}
+ \frac{ (2x+1)(1-x)^2}{9} \sum (n+1) x^{3n}
+ \frac{7}{27} \sum x^n
- \frac{2}{9} \sum (n+1) x^n
+ \frac{1}{9} \sum x^{3n}.$$

Still to do: Multiply by $x^{15}$ and find the coefficient of $x^k$.

Comment: Hint: Use partial fractions to rewrite
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^3)^2} = \frac{A}{1-x} + \frac{B}{1 - x^3} + \frac{C}{(1 - x^3)^2}
$$

Comment: Hum, it's been a long time since I've worked with partial fractions. Multiplying by $(1-x)(1-x^3)^2$ gives $$1 = A(1-x^3)^2 + B(1-x)(1-x^3)+C(1-x)\\=Ax^6+Bx^4-2Ax^3-(B+C)x+(A+B+C).$$ From here I don't really know how to get the values of $A, B, C$. It seems we should have $A=0$ and $B=-C$. But how does that help me?

Comment: Whoops, I made a silly mistake: $1 - x^3 = (1-x)(x^2 + x + 1)$ can be factored so really you have
$$
\frac{1}{(1 - x)^3 (x^2 + x + 1)^2} = \frac{A}{1-x} + \frac{B}{(1 - x)^2} + \frac{C}{(1 - x)^3} + \frac{Dx + E}{x^2 + x + 1} + \frac{Fx + G}{(x^2 + x + 1)^2} \, .
$$
You can always cheat and use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+1%2F%28%281-x%29^3%28x^2+%2B+x+%2B+1%29^2%29)!

Comment: I must have made a mistake because I don't quite come up with the same as Wolfram Alpha. Nonetheless, let's say I have $$\frac{1}{(1 - x)^3 (x^2 + x + 1)^2} = \frac{-7/27}{x-1} + \frac{2/9}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{-1/9}{(x-1)^3} + \frac{7/27 \cdot x + 8/27}{x^2 + x + 1} + \frac{2/9 \cdot x}{(x^2 + x + 1)^2}.$$ Theoretically, I have to multiply that by $x^{15}$ and set it equal to $\sum a_n x^n$. Then I need to find a formula for $a_n$. Again, I have no idea how to do that...

Comment: Here are some hints. Geometric series: $\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{n \geq 0} x^n$ and $\frac{1}{1 + x + x^2} = \frac{1}{1 - (-(x + x^2))}$, so you can also expand it as a geometric series.  For the higher powers: consider $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: First, I hope that I got the geometric series correct: $$\frac{7/27}{1-x}-\frac{2/9}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1/9}{(1-x)^3}=\frac{7}{27} \sum x^n - \frac{2}{9} \sum (n+1) x^n + \frac{1}{9} \sum \binom{n+2}{2} x^n.$$ Then I didn't find an expansion for $$\frac{1}{1 + x + x^2} = \frac{1}{1 - (-(x + x^2))}.$$ I only managed to expand it retreating to $$\frac{1}{1 + x + x^2} = \frac{1-x}{1-x^3}. = (1-x) \sum x^{3n}.$$ However, I still don't feel like I'm getting close to solving my original problem...

Comment: Oh, I think you're quite close!  The geometric series (and derivatives) look good.  I was thinking of
$$
\frac{1}{1 + x + x^2} = \frac{1}{1 - (-(x + x^2))} = \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n (x + x^2)^n
$$
but your answer is even better!  The coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1-x) \sum_{n \geq 0} x^{3n}$ is $1$ if $m \equiv 0$, $-1$ if $m \equiv 1$ and $0$ if $m \equiv 2$ mod $3$.  Anyway, use the derivative trick on $\frac{1}{1 + x + x^2}$ and you should be done!

Comment: Oh, you missed part of the partial fraction expansion: it should be $\frac{1}{9}\frac{2x + 1}{(1 + x + x^2)^2}$.  (Note the numerator is the derivative of the inside of the denominator, which makes things work out nicely!)

Comment: Oh right, thanks. However, I don't quite get the last hint in your previous comment. How should I differentiate again and why? If my expansion was good, like you said, I should have something like this now(see also my edited opening post): $$\frac{1}{(1 - x)^3 (x^2 + x + 1)^2} \\
=\frac{ (7x + 8)(1-x)}{27} \sum x^{3n}
+ \frac{ (2x+1)(1-x)^2}{9} \sum (n+1) x^{3n}
+ \frac{7}{27} \sum x^n
- \frac{2}{9} \sum (n+1) x^n
+ \frac{1}{9} \sum x^{3n}.$$ I still need to multiply by $x^{15}$ and find the coefficient of $x^k$.

Comment: Never mind, you worked it out without needing my hint.  Your summand looks wrong: what happened to $\frac{1}{9} \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{n+2}{2} x^n$?

Comment: By the way (to give you some hope) [the pattern of the coefficients is **very** apparent](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maclaurin+series+for+x^15%2F%28%281+-+x%29^3+%28x^2+%2B+x+%2B+1%29^2%29).

Comment: I must have confused $\frac{1}{1-x^3}$ with $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to have run out of steam, I'll finish off what you've started.  First note that you have a sign error in the second to last term: it should be $+ \frac{2}{9} \sum (n+1) x^n$.  Thus the series expansion for the generating function is
\begin{align*}
\frac{-7x^2 - x + 8}{27} \sum_{n \geq 0} x^{3n}
&+ \frac{2x^3 - 3x^2 + 1}{9} \sum_{n \geq 0} (n+1) x^{3n}\\
&+ \frac{7}{27} \sum_{n \geq 0} x^n
+ \frac{2}{9} \sum_{n \geq 0} (n+1) x^n + \frac{1}{18} \sum_{n \geq 0} (n^2 + 3n + 2) x^n \, .
\end{align*}

The coefficient of $x^m$ in these series depends on whether $m \equiv 0, 1$ or $2$ mod ${3}$.  If $m \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then the coefficient is
\begin{align}
&\frac{8}{27} + \frac{1}{9}\left(2 \left(\frac{m-3}{3} + 1\right) + \frac{m}{3} + 1 \right) + \frac{7}{27} + \frac{2}{9}(m+1) + \frac{1}{18}(m^2 + 3m + 2)\\
&= \frac{1}{18}m^2 + \frac{1}{2}m + 1 \, .
\end{align}
(Note that the second sum contributes **two** terms since $3n+3 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ as well.)  The last $3$ terms in the first line of the above formula remain the same whether $m \equiv 0, 1$ or $2$ mod ${3}$.

[**Edit:** A bit more on how I got this.  Let's consider the coefficient of $x^m$ in the first sum $\frac{-7x^2 - x + 8}{27} \sum_{n \geq 0} x^{3n}$.  Distributing, this sum is equal to
$$
\frac{-7}{27}\sum_{n \geq 0} x^{3n+2} + \frac{-1}{27} \sum_{n \geq 0} x^{3n+1} + \frac{8}{27} \sum_{n \geq 0} x^{3n} \, .
$$
If $m \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then the first to sums do not contribute to the coefficient of $x^m$.  Why?  Because all their powers of $x$ are congruent to $2$ and $1$, respectively.  Only the last sum contributes $\frac{8}{27}$ to the coefficient of $x^m$ when $n = m/3$.  Similarly, only the second sum contributes when $m \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, and the first when $m \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$.  The same considerations work for finding the coefficient of $x^m$ in $\frac{2x^3 - 3x^2 + 1}{9} \sum_{n \geq 0} (n+1) x^{3n}$.]

Similar calculations for $m \equiv 1, 2 \pmod{3}$ imply that the coefficient of $x^m$ is
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{18}m^2 + \frac{1}{2}m + 1 & \text{if } m \equiv 0 \pmod{3}\\
\frac{1}{18}m^2 + \frac{7}{18}m + \frac{5}{9} & \text{if } m \equiv 1 \pmod{3}\\
\frac{1}{18}m^2 + \frac{5}{18}m + \frac{2}{9} & \text{if } m \equiv 2 \pmod{3}
\end{cases} \, .
$$

As vonbrand points out in his answer, we could've instead factored the quadratic $1 + x + x^2$ into linear factors with third roots of unity, which would have lead to the same periodic behavior with period $3$.

Finally, as you pointed out, we still haven't taken care of that $x^{15}$.  It's very simple, though: to obtain the coefficient of $x^m$ in $\frac{x^{15}}{(1 - x)^3 (x^2 + x + 1)^2}$, we simply take the coefficient of $x^{m-15}$ in $\frac{1}{(1 - x)^3 (x^2 + x + 1)^2}$.  For instance, to compute the coefficient of $x^{22}$, we substitute $m = 22 - 15 = 7$ into the formula for $m \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, which yields $6$.

It turns out that these formulas can be simplified dramatically.  Using the formulas above (or Wolfram Alpha), we find that the Maclaurin series for the generating function is
$$
x^{15}+x^{16}+x^{17}+3 x^{18}+3 x^{19}+3 x^{20}+6 x^{21}+6 x^{22}+6 x^{23}+10 x^{24}+10 x^{25}+10 x^{26}+15 x^{27}+15 x^{28}+15 x^{29}+ \cdots \, .
$$
These coefficients are the triangular numbers $T_n = \binom{n+2}{2} = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}$ repeated $3$ times each.  This can also be seen from the formulas above: letting
\begin{align*}
f(m) &= \frac{1}{18}m^2 + \frac{1}{2}m + 1\\
g(m) &= \frac{1}{18}m^2 + \frac{7}{18}m + \frac{5}{9}\\
h(m) &= \frac{1}{18}m^2 + \frac{5}{18}m + \frac{2}{9}
\end{align*}
then
$$
f(3n) = g(3n+1) = h(3n+2) = \frac{1}{2} n^2 + \frac{3}{2}n + 1 = \binom{n+2}{2} \, .
$$
Thus a simpler formula for the coefficient of $x^n$ is
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n-15}{3} \right\rfloor + 2\right) \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n-15}{3} \right\rfloor + 1\right) \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks for picking up where I failed. However, I still don't understand this: $$\frac{8}{27} + \frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{m}{3} + 1 + 2 \left(\frac{m-3}{3} + 1\right) \right)$$. Incidentally, this is exactly the part where I got lost before because I didn't know how to handle those quadratic terms...

Comment: I've edited to address your concern.  Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Thanks again, I understand now.

Comment: One humble correction to your excellent answer: If we substitute $m = 22 - 15 = 7$ the actual formula that gives $6$ (which is, I suppose, correct) is the one for $m \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

OK, use generating functions. Note that $1 - z^3 = (1 - \omega z) (1 - \omega^2 z) (1 - z)$, where $\omega = -\frac{1}{2} + \mathrm{i} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\omega^3 = 1$:
\begin{align}
[z^n] z^{15} (1 + z &+ z^2 + \ldots) (1 + z^3 + z^6 + \ldots)^2 \\
  &= [z^{n - 15}] \frac{1}{(1 - z) (1 - z^3)^2} \\
  &= [z^{n - 15}] \frac{1}{(1 - z)^3 (1 - \omega z)^2 (1 - \omega^2 z)^2}
\end{align}
This can be split into partial fractions, but the coefficients are very ugly. They can be simplified by $\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0$ and $\omega^3 = 1$. Use of a computer algebra system is mandatory.

Once you've got the partial fractions, you can use:
$$
\binom{-m}{k} = (-1)^k \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1}
$$
The imaginary components cancel out, and you get real coefficients. One way to express them is to use Euler's formula:
$$
\omega^n
  = \exp( \mathrm{i} \frac{2 \pi n}{3} )
  = \cos \frac{2 \pi n}{3} + \mathrm{i} \sin \frac{2 \pi n}{3}
$$

Comment: Hum, thanks a lot for your answer. This would explain some of the trouble I've had. However, I have a question: I noticed you left out the part that leads to a factor of $x^{15}$ in my approach (when building the generating functions in the first place). Is that because it doesn't affect the coefficient of $x^n$ anyway? Sorry if it's obvious, I've had a long night...

Comment: The coefficient of $x^n$ in $x^{15} f(x)$ is just the coefficient of $x^{n-15}$ in $f(x)$.

Comment: @Amarus, you are right. I forgot that factor. Fixing...